# Google api : Infowindow Content Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, if-statement, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to show a [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) on Google Maps. In [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/) I fetch the data from ajax and set and content of infowindow.

```
infoWindowContent = [
                      ['<div class="info_content"><h3>'+ this.tc_city_name + '</h3>'+ if this.tc_city_description !=='null'){ +'<p>' + this.tc_city_description + '</p>'} + '<p><a href = "' + this.tc_city_web_site + '" target="_blank">' + this.tc_city_web_site + '</a></p>'+ '</div>']
];
```

This code when I use the if condition then it give syntax error, can you please tell me, how I use the if condition in this code.

Comment: `if (something) { infoWindowContent = '...'; } else { infoWindowContent = '...'; }`

Comment: when i use if condition for city name , description, and web site than it may make my code bigger

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `+=` [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) to add more content to your variable:

```
infoWindowContent = '<div class="info_content"><h3>' + this.tc_city_name + '</h3>';

if (this.tc_city_description !== 'null') {
    infoWindowContent += '<p>' + this.tc_city_description + '</p>';
}

infoWindowContent += '<p><a href = "' + this.tc_city_web_site + '" target="_blank">' + this.tc_city_web_site + '</a></p>' + '</div>';
```

By the way you are missing a `(` in your `if` condition:

```
if (condition) { 
    // do something
}
```